# JAVA: Populating an array then display using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to populate an array [C], then display it using a for loop.. I'm new to arrays and this is confusing the hell out of me, any advice is appreciated!

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int A[] = new int[5];
    int B[] = new int[5];
    String C[] = new String[5];
    int D[] = new int[5];

    C[] = {"John", "Cook", "Fred"};
    for(String name: C)
        System.out.println(C);
    }}
```

Comment: so what is your particular question?

Comment: Basically, I've got to populate array 'C' then display it using a for-loop

Comment: Think about what you're trying to do with your current loop. The `foreach` loop works as: *`for each item in iterable`*. You're printing out the iterable for each item, not the item itself (name).

Answer (score 1):

You can define and populate an array in two ways. Using literals:

```
    String c[] = {"John", "Cook", "Fred"};
    for(String name : c) { // don't forget this { brace here!
        System.out.println(name); // you want to print name, not c!
    }
```

Or by setting each index element:

```
    int d[] = new int[2];
    d[0] = 2;
    d[1] = 3;
    for(int num: d) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
```

(You can only use the literal when you first define the statement, so

```
    String c[];
    c = {"John", "Cook", "Fred"};
```

Will cause an "illegal start of expression" error.)

Comment: What works? Which variables? And do you mean `static`? Java doesn't have a `global` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You want to print name instead of C.

Answer (score 0):

`C` is the name of the array, while `name` is the name of the String variable. Therefore you must print `name` instead of `C`

```
   System.out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
    System.out.println(C[i]);
    }
```

## here 2 is the last index of the array C

> You cannot simply print an array you have to provide an index to your item

where C[0] is john and C[1] is Cook and so on

and if you want to use a for each loop then this is how it goes

```
for(Iterator<String> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    String item = i.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying at what index you want to add the element.

Example:

```
C[0] = "hej";
```

Also, print the element in the array, not the actual array. (System.out.println(name);)